# How can I use cq5 api to copy(overwrite) child Pages into another Pages

Tags: adobe, aem

I got a task to create a workflow to copy the common contents(child pages) in a master page into slave pages. just like

masterPage

|＿childPage1

|＿childPage2

|＿childPage3

↓

slavePage

|＿

|＿

|＿

↓

slavePage

|＿childPage1

|＿childPage2

|＿childPage3

Can anyone give me some helps? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PageManager is the api you are looking for: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/index.html?com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html

In your custom workflow step just inject yourself a ResourceResolverFactor, obtain a ResourceResolver and adapt it to PageManager. Use it's copy method(s) to perform actual copying of a page.